# Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Pardon me, I am new to SQL. I have built a form that allows users to input values.

I am trying to remove the possibility of SQL injection, therefore taking the appropriate measures in my programming.

Here is my code using $POST, vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$dbh=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","toplist");

// Checking the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbh))
  {
  echo "Could not connect do SQL database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$serverip=$_POST['post_serverip'];
$serverport=$_POST['post_serverport'];
$servertitle=$_POST['post_servertitle'];
$serverdesc=$_POST['post_serverdesc'];
$serverwebsite=$_POST['post_serverwebsite'];
$listingtype=$_POST['post_listingtype'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO servers (serverip, serverport, servertitle,     serverdesc, serverwebsite, listingtype) VALUES     ('$serverip','$serverport','$servertitle','$serverdesc','$serverwebsite','$listingtype')");
```

I heard prepared statements reduce/disable the risk of SQL injection, so I converted my code over using prepared statements:

```
$dbh=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","toplist");
global $DBH; 
// Checking the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbh))
  {
  echo "Could not connect do SQL database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Inserting input values into its respected row serverip, serverport, servertitle,     serverdesc, serverwebsite, listingtype
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO servers (name, value) VALUES (:serverip, :serverip,     :serverport, :serverport, :server desc, :server desc, :serverwebsite, :serverwebsite,     :listing type, :listing type)");
$stmt->bind_param(':post_serverip', $serverip);
$stmt->bind_param(':post_serverport', $serverport);
$stmt->bind_param(':post_servertitle', $servertitle);
$stmt->bind_param(':post_serverdesc', $serverdesc);
$stmt->bind_param(':post_serverwebsite', $serverwebsite);
$stmt->bind_param(':post_listingtype', $listingtype);
```

**But I get the error:** Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object .. Everything else seems to be fine, because this is the only error I receive.

I have done some searching and I think the error may be caused by the connection to my database. **Does any body know for sure what this is caused by?**

Comment: Well, your VALUES most certainly **outweigh** your `binParam`'s in your second body of code. Plus, you have colons for only these two `:serverip, :serverip` but not the others. You're also mixing [**mysqli**](http://php.net/mysqli) with [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), so another `X` against you. `bindParam` is PDO, while `bind_param` is `mysqli`

Comment: For PDO connection, use `$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);`

Comment: You're welcome. You have 6 `bindParam`'s and what looks to be 15 `VALUES`, there are spaces in your column names or missing commas in there. If your column name is called (for example) `server desc` (which is in there twice, by the way) you need to use backticks to wrap it with.

Comment: I have decided to go with PDO. Oh and that was my mistake, there are suppose to be 6 bindParams and 6 VALUES. I took the code for PDO connection that you gave me, but I believe that I configured it incorrectly: $dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=toplist", root, ); because it is not working. The database does not have a password by the way, so should I leave it blank or remove it from the PDO connection?

Comment: Yes you can try removing the password parameter, although I never had to, I always use a password.

Comment: Try using it this way: `$mysql_hostname = 'xxx'; $mysql_username = 'xxx'; $mysql_dbname = 'xxx'; $mysql_password = '';` then do `$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);`

Comment: That fixed it! No more errors are being displayed, and the "Server added" message is showing up! However, none of the values are being inputted into the rows.. Did I write the prepare code wrong? Should it be (:serverip, $serverip, :serverport, $serverport) instead of (:serverip, :serverport, :servertitle, etc) I have 6 rows: serverip,serverport,servertitle,serverdesc, serverwebsite, listingtype ALL inside of 1 table: servers

Comment: Great! I'm putting something together you can try and will post it below as a (TEST) answer. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted for you below. I edited it, so you may need to reload it.

Comment: In case you may not have seen my edited comment above, I edited my post below, so you may have to reload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

```
$serverip=$_POST['post_serverip'];
$serverport=$_POST['post_serverport'];
$servertitle=$_POST['post_servertitle'];
$serverdesc=$_POST['post_serverdesc'];
$serverwebsite=$_POST['post_serverwebsite'];
$listingtype=$_POST['post_listingtype'];

$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = '';

$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO servers (serverip, serverport, servertitle, serverdesc, serverwebsite, listingtype)
            VALUES (:serverip, :serverport, :servertitle, :serverdesc, :serverwebsite, :listingtype)");

$stmt->bindParam(':serverip', $serverip);
$stmt->bindParam(':serverport', $serverport);
$stmt->bindParam(':servertitle', $servertitle);
$stmt->bindParam(':serverdesc', $serverdesc);
$stmt->bindParam(':serverwebsite', $serverwebsite);
$stmt->bindParam(':listingtype', $listingtype);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

### Numbered array method

```
$serverip=$_POST['post_serverip'];
$serverport=$_POST['post_serverport'];
$servertitle=$_POST['post_servertitle'];
$serverdesc=$_POST['post_serverdesc'];
$serverwebsite=$_POST['post_serverwebsite'];
$listingtype=$_POST['post_listingtype'];

$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = '';

$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO servers (serverip, serverport, servertitle, serverdesc, serverwebsite, listingtype)
            VALUES (:serverip, :serverport, :servertitle, :serverdesc, :serverwebsite, :listingtype)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $serverip);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $serverport);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $servertitle);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $serverdesc);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $serverwebsite);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $listingtype);

$stmt->execute(array(
':serverip' => $serverip, 
':serverport' => $serverport, 
':servertitle' => $servertitle, 
':serverdesc' => $serverdesc, 
':serverwebsite' => $serverwebsite, 
':listingtype' => $listingtype));
```

---

### Original answer to help out OP with examples

Try it like this and replace `column_1` and `value_1` etc. to match your columns and variables.

**N.B.:** Use underscores and not hyphens in case you want to space out words.

### Method #1

```
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = '';

$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO servers (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6)
            VALUES (:value_1, :value_2, :value_3, :value_4, :value_5, :value_6)");
            
$stmt->bindParam(':column_1', $value_1);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_2', $value_2);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_3', $value_3);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_4', $value_4);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_5', $value_5);
$stmt->bindParam(':column_6', $value_6);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

### "OR" this method: (Method #2)

**Don't mix them both together. Use one or the other.**

NOTE: Keep it like this `$stmt->bindParam(1, $serverip);` etc. keeping the `1,2,3,4,5,6` and then replacing `$value_x` by `$serverip` etc.

```
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = '';

$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO servers (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6)
            VALUES (:value_1, :value_2, :value_3, :value_4, :value_5, :value_6)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $value_1);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value_2);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $value_3);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $value_4);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $value_5);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $value_6);

$stmt->execute(array(
':column_1' => $value_1, 
':column_2' => $value_2, 
':column_3' => $value_3, 
':column_4' => $value_4, 
':column_5' => $value_5, 
':column_6' => $value_6));
```

Comment: Tried both, and neither seemed to input the values into my table. One moment, posting picture of code.

Comment: Did you change `column_1` and `value_1` etc. to your column names and variables? @GangDonIt

Comment: Here is a picture of the current code: http://i.imgur.com/HObVbPi.png (using example #2)

Comment: You're mixing both of my "different" examples together. Notice the two different code bodies seperated by `or this method:` @GangDonIt - Use one `OR` the other, not both mixed up. Notice the first one ends with `$stmt->execute();` then that's it. The other one has `execute` in the array.

Comment: Plus I noticed you put in `$stmt->bindParam(postserverip, $serverip);` instead of keeping the number (1,2,3,4,5,6) `$stmt->bindParam(1, $value_1);` etc. @GangDonIt - The numbers sequences must stay like that, as in example #2 That's why you're getting an error. Keep the numbers the way they are, but replace the second parameter with your $value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46368/discussion-between-gang-don-it-and-fred-ii)

Comment: Just curious to know if you tried **"Numbered array method"** in an edit I did under the first one that worked. @GangDonIt

Comment: No I did not, in comparison, how would it be better than the first one?

Comment: It's just a different style. @GangDonIt Some like to use that method.